# CPU time accounting: report cumulative total CPU time

Tags: kernel, accounts

There are about 15 users on a computation server running jobs via SSH, Jupyter, or the web version of RStudio. Every user has a standard Linux user account, each process is owned by the user also if it is executed via Jupyter or RStudio.

I would like to do some see an overview of who is using a lot of resources. This could be I/O, RAM, or CPU time over a longer period of time. E.g. how many CPU hours dead each user need last year or this month?

The kernel support [process accounting](http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-mini/Process-Accounting.html). The command `sa -m` is almost doing what I want. But I can't find documentation on which users are included in this list and how to include all users.

- How can I control which users are listed?
- How long is the data stored?
- Is there a graphical tool like `Munin` which does support process accounting?
- Is there something similar for I/O and RAM usage?

See also:

- https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/linux-system-monitoring-acct
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/107456/whats-the-fairest-way-to-monitor-total-cpu-time-per-user